# Is it possible to write a cross platform extension for both VSCode and Visual Studio 2022?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, visual-studio-2022, visual-studio-extensions

My understanding is that in writing an extension for VSCode, the extension can be packaged as a VSIX file, which is what Visual Studio uses as the extension file.

Would the extension written for VSCode need to be entirely re-written for use on visual studio, or is there some way to provide some similar operation between both IDEs with less redundancy in a practically repeat codebase?

Comment: what is the language for VSC: JavaScript, what is the language for VS (up to the versions I know of): C++, VSC has a completely different API so not very likely

Comment: "the extension can be packaged as a VSIX file, which is what Visual Studio uses as the extension file" is just an illusion. The file extension doesn't matter at all, as VS .vsix are completely different from VS Code .vsix (manifest format and contents). They are just ZIP packages and incompatible with each other. Microsoft's choice of sticking to the same file extension is a mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, VS Code extensions are javascript-based, while Visual Studio extensions are c#/.net based; I haven't heard of a way to write a single extension for both editors.

Having said that ...

> is there some way to provide some similar operation between both IDEs with less redundancy in a practically repeat codebase?

Language Servers are meant to help with exactly that!

- [Language Server overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/language-server-protocol?view=vs-2022)
- [Consuming a language server in VS Code (javascript)](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/language-server-extension-guide)
- [Consuming a language server in Visual Studio (C#)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/adding-an-lsp-extension?view=vs-2022)